# Xcode hangs while scrolling through build settings if I have about more than 20 configurations

Tags: ios, xcode

I have multiple configurations in my iOS project, like about more than 20 configurations. I use so many configurations because my requirement is to have same code base with multiple bundle-ids. I don't want to create multiple targets as it would be difficult to maintain it amongst the team and source control. I conditionally check the bundle-id and code accordingly.

Now my problem is that when I go to Build Settings tab and scroll there, then the Xcode gets slow and hangs since there are a lot of configurations. This causes a lot of time being wasted. Any solution or suggestion to overcome this?

Comment: Have you ever managed to find any solution? I have the same problem, around 30 configurations and Xcode being super slow when I scroll to the `Signing` section of the build settings.

Comment: Could not find any solution yet.